# Load xml data to file from oracle reader

Tags: c#, oracle10g

I am calling oracle package, to get xml file from the package into oracleDataReader. How can i load that into xmldocument?
Here is the code:

```
OracleDataReader reader = new OracleDataReader();

     //calling package here and reading xml file into reader... 

     reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

    while(reader.Read())
    {                            
        XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
        doc.LoadXml("what should i enter here to add the reader xml file???");    

    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try

```
doc.LoadXml(reader.GetString(0));
```

IF the above does not work for you please provide information on the statement that is run by `cmd` and the DB structure/field definition etc.